# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT overwritten on deploy

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a dotnet core application I am deploying remotely on a test server. The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable should be set to "Development" on the remote machine. Each time I deploy, the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable is overwritten with "Develop". I have to go into the IIS Admin Configuration Editor and replace the incorrect ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable each time I deploy.

Can anyone help me understand why this variable is being overwritten each time I deploy?

Here is my web.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <buildProviders>
        <remove extension=".xml" />
        <add extension=".xml" 
            type="System.Web.Compilation.ForceCopyBuildProvider" />
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
              modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
          arguments=".\project.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" 
          stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true">
      <environmentVariables>
        <clear />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" 
            value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my Dev.pubxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <PublishFramework>netcoreapp1.0</PublishFramework>
    <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
  <publishUrl>\\server</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>wwwroot\node_modules</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    <UseMsDeployExe>true</UseMsDeployExe>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="SkipNodeModules">
      <AbsolutePath>wwwroot\node_modules</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the issue/solution for anyone else having this issue.

- The web.config file deployed did not have the environmentVariable entry until I edited the environment variables in IIS Admin.
- I altered the web.config and web.Debug.config files in my deploy and now I am getting the correct environment variables on the IIS server.
- The web.config file should match the one in my question above, but the web.Debug.Config now looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <aspNetCore>
    <environmentVariables>
       <clear />
       <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" 
          value="Development"  xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </environmentVariables>
  </aspNetCore>
</configuration>
```